# My Galaxy mini having trouble with charging

Tags: charging

Today I noticed that my Galaxy Mini is not charging properly.

In morning it was switched off even after charging for the whole night. Some weeks ago the same problem had occured, but some time after when I plugged it in with the USB cable it was getting charged. When I connected the charger, it was working fine.

Well, my problems don't stop there. Today I did all the possible tricks, but it doesn't charge. In fact it is showing the charging symbol, but its not increasing. It's not even showing the charging percentage. When I connect it with the PC via USB cable it is charging and battery level increasing too, but it again suddenly decreases or again increases.

What is the problem? And how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1):

The battery may be ok.

I had this problem and fixed it.

1) Plug the phone into a charger.

2) The pins get loose, so press the battery towards the pins and press the on button.

3) Once the phone starts to boot up, you can take the pressure off and replace the back onto the phone.

Whoolahhh!

Answer (score -1):

Try using a different battery. Samsung phones have user-replaceable batteries, and your current one may be defective.

Comment: Must be the exact battery that is for Galaxy Mini - your first sentence is sounding like "try another battery from elsewhere"... :) Might be best to re-edit your answer to be more specific :)